# MYSQL join two different columns from two different table as single column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with no relation between them. The following is a query I've tried:

```
SELECT table1.columnName, table2.columnName AS newColumn
FROM table1, table2.
```

I am unable to get the results I need.

Comment: Please show the column structure of both tables and also what is your expected output ?

Comment: if there is no relation, then just do separate select query

Comment: Right now you are creating a full Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the columns combined into a single column, without a `where` clause, that's going to give you a (probably larger than you want) Cartesian product, but you can do it with something like:

```
select concat (tbl1.col1, tbl2.col2) from tbl1, tbl2
```

If you want a single column with values from both tables (rather than concatenating them), just use something like:

```
select col1 as col from tbl1
union
select col2 as col from tbl2
```

Comment: thanKz paxdiablo... second one works for me when used with UNION ALL

Answer (score 2):

There can be several queries depends on scenario. However, if you want to join two different columns of two different tables into a single column without WHERE then you can do like:

SELECT CONCAT( table1.col1 , table2.col2) AS colName
FROM Table table1,Table table2.